# react utils function return tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I have a component which has multiple fields in the form.. 2 of them is type of bytes. The idea is that for each field from these 2, I have to:

- first check if it exists in ipfs and if so, show the url of the ipfs
- If it's not in ipfs, then I have to do `utf8string` on it.

I don't want to put this logic in the component. So I am thinking of creating an utils function. The problem with this utils is that I somehow need to return `<a href={ipfsUrl}` from it.

The question is: Is it a good idea to have a utils function which returns a tag(`<a>`) in this case ?

Comment: When you create a function that returns a tag, you are creating a pure function component. I don't see any problem on that.  where do you create that component in the folder architecture?

Comment: `src/utils/test123.tsx` here ..

Comment: As I see it this question is very opinion-based. And depends on how do you want to structure your project.

Comment: what is ipf here?